# Oracle : How to grant to a ROLE the ability to affect a ROLE to a USER?

Tags: oracle

I have a role : ADMIN_ROLE

I'm connected as ADMIN_ROLE and created a TEST_USER and TEST_ROLE

I would like to be able to affect TEST_ROLE to TEST_USER using ADMIN_ROLE

I did (using system user) :

```
Grant create role to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
Grant create user to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
```

but when executing from ADMIN_ROLE :

```
Grant TEST_ROLE to TEST_USER
```

I'm receiving error: ORA 1932 - ADMIN option not granted for role string.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: Not a question for [so]. You'd probably do better asking on [dba.se]

Answer (score 1):

You must fist grant the role (test_role) to the user (admin_role) with admin option, like this:

```
grant TEST_ROLE to ADMIN_ROLE with admin option;
```

I suggest that you name your users in a different way. `admin_role` is a user in your case, it would be better to name it `admin_user`.